# Pass output of a script to another script using sys.argv

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to take the output of one script and pass it using sys.argv to my python script.

The question I have is whether there's a way to accomplish this similar to

```
python runfile.py $(node parse.js)
```

For testing, runfile.py just consists of:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

But, as you might've guessed, that just logs ['runfile.py'].

Am I totally barking up the wrong tree here? If so, can someone explain or link to an explanation of how to pass the output of, say, a javascript file to a python script?

Edit: is there a way to mark the $(node parse.js) part as a separate argument that should be evaluated?

Comment: When I tested it your program returned ```['test.py', '$(node', 'parse.js)']```, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the output of `node parse.js` to your python script via command line arguments (`sys.argv`) you could use [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) and [unix pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_pipe):

`node parse.js | python runfile.py`

And edit runfile.py to look like:

```
import sys
print sys.stdin
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the move I settled on.